# How do I insert non breaking space character &nbsp; in a JSF page?

Tags: jsf, facelets

How do I insert a non breaking space character in JSF page
like I can in HTML using `&nbsp;`?
Is there such a tag in JSF?

Comment: Related (and technically a duplicate with a way much better explanation): [Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced(line: 42) The entity “nbsp” was referenced, but not declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012327/error-parsing-page-xhtml-error-tracedline-42-the-entity-nbsp-was-referenc)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

this will work

```
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
```

Comment: Why is a `<h:outputText>` required?

Comment: Indeed, using the HTML numbers and not other html-shortcuts is the way to go.

Answer (score 53):

Putting the HTML number directly did the trick for me:

```
&#160;
```

Comment: Oh, I just wanna give the answer right now. Glad, I have not overseen yours.

Answer (score 19):

If your using the RichFaces library you can also use the tag rich:spacer which will add an "invisible" image with a given length and height. Usually much easier and prettier than to add tons of nbsp;.

Where you want your space to show you simply add:

```
<rich:spacer height="1" width="2" />
```

Comment: +1 althoug this wasn't exactly asked here, but your answer was helpful to me (regaring the title)

Comment: same here, this tag also exists in PrimeFaces: `<p:spacer />`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use primefaces `<p:spacer width="10" height="10" />`

Answer (score 7):

Eventually, you can try this one, if just using `&nbsp;` fails...

```
<h:outputText value="& nbsp;" escape="false"/>
```

(like Tom, I added a space between `&` and `nbsp;` )

Comment: I feel escaping is such of importance, that this might give way to non-secure solutions. Giving up escaping for only a nbsp / other html elements is tricky. Besides, the 'space' might be forgotten. This is quite verbose, while there are shorter alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is:

```
<h:outputText value=" " />
```

Comment: It is not the easiest way, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the parser would complain if I used the `&nbsp;` entity in my page.  After a little research, I learned that if I added a DOCTYPE declaration to the beginning of the page, the entity was allowed.  I use this DOCTYPE declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

A side effect of this is that the resulting code (as seen by using the "view source" feature of a web browser) doesn't actually contain the `&nbsp;` entity.  It instead includes the actual characters that represent a nonbreaking space.  Although it works, it's not really what I want.  I'm still looking for a way to make the parser not replace the entity with the character.

More information here: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1576

Answer (score 3):

You can use `primefaces` library

```
 <p:spacer width="10" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11637485)

Comment: @ihebiheb was take +6, dont tell me it's wrong, because i know its true, just you say blah blah..

Comment: Your answer was flagged as too short because it lacks details. I suggest you to add details to let users understand "why" your solution could be a good one or maybe the best one. Adding detailslet users adapt your solution to slightly different problems.

Answer (score 1):

just to add to options: `<h:outputText value="&amp;nbsp;" escape="false"/>` worked

Comment: I feel escaping is such of importance, that this might be give way to non-secure solutions. Giving up escaping for only a nbsp / other html elements is tricky. Besides, this is quite verbose, while there are shorter alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to give 160 . 141 will also work. For the value field provide value="&#141" .