# Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, html-entities

I'd like to use non breaking spaces in my JSF page. I know, in plain HTML I could use `&nbsp;` for this and this works fine. However, when I put those `&nbsp;` in a Facelets page, then it errors as follows:

> Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: show some more code... where idi you placed that `&nbsp;` exactly ?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Facelets is a XML based view technology. XML has only [five predefined entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML). The `&nbsp;` is not among them. It works only when used in plain HTML or in legacy JSP (note: it doesn't work in JSPX as that's also XML based!).

To fix this, you either need to declare the entity yourself in the doctype of the very XHTML file containing the `&nbsp;` entity,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> 
]>
```

or, better, use the (hexa)decimal notation instead:

```
&#xA0; or &#160;
```

In an average IDE it should be trivial to perform a "find and replace in all files" and replace every occurrence of `&nbsp;` by `&#xA0;`.

Comment: Use the hex or decimal notation. :-)

Comment: &#xA0; solved the drifting decimal point right alignment problem when incorporated into the pattern #,##0.00&#xA0;;(#,##0.00) within a Jasper Report/Library/Studio .JRXML file.

Answer (score 15):

For me the following doctype enables `&nbsp;`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: With this I was able to do something like <xsl:variable name="size" select="substring-before(s:td[3], '&nbsp;')" />

Answer (score 14):

Try using `&amp;#160;`. for more information on entities you can refer following url [HTML ISO-8859-1 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Answer (score 11):

Add below to the top of the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Why did this get two negatives I wonder.  It's maybe a bit too concise but it is correct.  The entity was not defined in the doctype and it is defined when using the spec provided.   A year later, someone posts the exact same thing and gets two upvotes.

Comment: I agree with @Dilapidus, this worked perfect for me in Chrome and JBoss EAP 7 and Facelets Version 2.2

Answer (score 9):

1. `<![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>` should work fine. This *does not* work inside attribute value, though.
2. Alternatively, as long as `&amp;` is a predefined entity in XML, you could try `&amp;nbsp;`  - worked for me with XML based JSP. This should work within attributes as well.