# Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 45] The entity "laquo" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: jsf, special-characters, el

```
#{'&#171;'.concat(text)}
```

It's ok. **But**

```
#{'&laquo;'.concat(text)}
```

Exception:
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 45] The entity "laquo" was referenced, but not declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use facelets then this is the expected behaviour.
You should use the hexadecimal notation or declare the entity you wish to use in the doctype.Have a look at these websites for more details.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

[Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012327/the-entity-nbsp-was-referenced-but-not-declared)