# javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /template.xhtml: The entity “nbsp” was referenced, but not declared

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, html-entities

I know the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012327/error-parsing-page-xhtml-error-tracedline-42-the-entity-nbsp-was-referenc). But the issue is time to time it reset back even I change to `&#xA0;` instead `&nbsp;` I am using JDeveloper.

please tell me how to fix this permanently? also where to include this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> 
 ]>
```

Comment: Include that at the top of your page

Comment: @PredragMaric   when I add there, I got another weird message.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error again upgrading a project from 3.x to 4.5.x and the above also did not fix it for me.  What works according to my notes was adding this as the first line of the xhtml file:
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`