# JSF PanelGrid space between elements

Tags: jsf, primefaces, panel

I have problem with h:panelGrid control. I try to put some elements in it and make space between something like:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="Output1 is: "/>
    <h:inputText/>

    <h:outputLabel value="Output2 is: "/>
    <h:inputText/>

    <h:outputLabel value="Output3 is: "/>
    <h:inputText/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And when i use `"columns=2"` parameter, it's display properly. But i try to make space only between 1st and 2nd. Not every all components.

I try to use `<br/>` but it doesn't work.

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 version.

Comment: You try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356220/how-to-insert-space-in-jsf-page

Comment: you do realize that you don't close the outputLabel tag. is this the original code ?

Answer (score -2):

Just need put

`<h:outputText value="&#160;" />`

twice after some item to make space (in this case).

Thanks to @RongNK