# Whitespace being removed between word and link in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces

I am attempting to learn a bit about Java Faces using the [Oracle/Sun JavaEE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html#giqzd) as I learn about Java EE in general. I ran into something that's been bothering me that I can't seem to fix.

In an xhtml page the following block of code:

```
<p>I've made your <h:link outcome="personal" value="personal greeting page!" 
                    includeViewParams="true">
                  <f:param name="Result" value="#{hello.name}"/>
             </h:link>
</p>
```

Get's displayed like:

> > I've made your[personal greeting page!](http://personal.xhtml)

For some reason it's not recognizing the space between the word your, and the start of the link. When I look at the HTML source, it looks like its been trimmed out entirely. I've tried both manually adding an `&nbsp;` and I've tried turning whitespace compression off in the WEB-INF/faces-config.xml

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour and a way to fix it?

Comment: How about adding the space in the value of the `<h:link>`? `<h:link value=" personal greeting page!" ... >`

Comment: I get an underline of the space, and the space itself becomes a link.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [how to insert space in jsf page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356725/3242674)

Inserting the following tag will force a space to be rendered in a JSF page.

```
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
```

Ex:

```
<p>I've made your<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
   <h:link outcome="personal" value="personal greeting page!" includeViewParams="true">
       <f:param name="Result" value="#{hello.name}"/>
   </h:link>
</p>
```

Now correctly renders:

> > I've made your [personal greeting page!](http://personal.xhtml)