# Print &nbsp; in empty table cell

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to create JSF table with clickable rows. Example:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:commandLink value="User name" actionListener="#{bean.sort}" style="text-decoration:none;">
            <f:ajax render="@form" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
    <h:commandLink value="#{item.userName}" action="#{accounts.pageRedirect}" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{accounts.sessionValue}" value="#{item.number}" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:column>
```

But when I have empty cell the row is shrink. I tried this solution

```
 table { empty-cells: show; }
```

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML/emptycells.html

But according to the article it's not working for IE. So I need to use `&nbsp;`

How I can implement some logic in `h:commandLink value="#{item.userName}"` to print `&nbsp;` if the value is empty?

P.S I need something like this I suppose:

```
value="#{item.number == null ? &nbsp; : item.number}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `rendered` attribute to conditionnaly display content:

```
<h:column>
     <h:commandLink value="#{item.userName}" action="#{accounts.pageRedirect}" style="text-decoration:none;" rendered="#{item.number != null}">
          <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{accounts.sessionValue}" value="#{item.number}" />
     </h:commandLink>

     <h:outputText value="&#160;" rendered="#{item.number == null}" />
</h:column>
```

See also the following links to understand why I replace `&nbsp;` by `&#160;`:

- [How do I insert non breaking space character &nbsp; in a JSF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356220/how-do-i-insert-non-breaking-space-character-nbsp-in-a-jsf-page)
- [Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012327/error-parsing-page-xhtml-error-tracedline-42-the-entity-nbsp-was-referenc)